# How to export my private key from MyCrypto

Tags: metamask, private-key, mnemonic, mycrypto

I'm using [MyCrypto](https://mycrypto.com/) (an Ethereum and EVM-based software wallet). I created a new wallet with 12-word mnemonic phrase. I wrote down the words and started using the wallet.

I need to get the private key that MyCrypto derived from those mnemonics.

I created a MetaMask wallet with the exact same mnemonics in the same order and it created a different account, thus I assume that the private key that Metamask derived from those mnemonics is not the same that MyCrypto derived for the same mnemonics.

Metamask has an option to let you see the private key. But I don't see such an option in MyCrypto. I need to export the private key MyCrypto derived from the mnemonics to do something with it.

I know I can stick with Metamask to create a new wallet and export the private key when needed, but I really want to know if it's possible to do the same from MyCrypto.

Any idea is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to figure it out.
We just have to go to the 'Wallet Info' tab and it will show the private key:

[image]